# How to solve an inequality involving the floor function?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following disequation:
$$\left \lfloor \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right\rfloor < \frac{n^2+3n}{8}.$$
Which is the right method to solve that?

My thougths so far: I wrote the term 
$$\left \lfloor \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right\rfloor = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-r}{6}$$
where $r=0, \dots, 5$, but I was wondering if there is another method to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   \left \lfloor \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right\rfloor &< n^2+4n \\
   \left \lfloor \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{6} - ( n^2+4n)\right\rfloor &< 0 \\
   \left \lfloor \frac{-5n^2-21n+2}{6} \right\rfloor &< 0 \\
   \frac{-5n^2-21n+2}{6} &< 0 \\
\end{align}

The rest is standard stuff.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. What if I had $\frac{n^2-3n}{8}$ on the right side? We couldn't use the same trick. Is there another method?

Comment: @DanielDoz : I can't think of anything simple.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\lfloor X-(n^2+4n) \rfloor =\lfloor X\rfloor -(n^2+4n)$$

$$\lfloor Y \rfloor <0 \iff Y <0$$

Your disequation is then equivalent to

$$-5n^2-23n+2 <0$$